# Polyphone instrument looping

Tags: software, midi

I'm trying to loop an instrument in Polyphone. I've got the sample looping fine, but the instrument seems to completely ignore the looping settings I've set for the instrument.

All guides I have read tell me to set "Loop playback" to `1`, but these are the only options I have:

[image]

I've tried the second option, but it hasn't helped. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the program showed that the setting I had set pictographically hadn't actually saved, and showed me this:

[image: The expected screen]

It now functions. I think this is a bug. The moral of this story? If in doubt, turn it off and on again.